# How to write modular (plug-in) applications with Go?

Tags: shared-libraries, go

I understand that the Go programming language doesn't really support dynamic linking.  This makes me wonder, what would somebody do if they wanted to write an application that supported third party (or otherwise contributed) plug-ins?

It seems the typical response is that Go compiles quickly, so just recompile, but I don't find this all that practical for system administrators.  The Apache web server for example, has an amazing number of modules that can be configured to be loaded (or not loaded) very easily.

Is the only option left to use sockets or other IPC for plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do, is, set up an API through, say, channel over pipe. And tell the plugin author to issue an exe that communicate over this pipe.

This is similar to how Chrome works today.

This is [a way](http://rogpeppe.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/bidirectional-rpc-with-netchan/) to achieve that over `netchan`.

**Note:** the netchan pacakage is deprecated, but the idea is to use RPC over unix pipes.

Comment: The Go `netchan` package was an experiment; it is being deleted. http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=0ad345711d0f

Comment: @peterSO, the idea is however the same, RPC through unix pipe. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the cool thing about that is, short of sharing libraries, you can decouple the programming language from the parent project.